# Linking flash to OOP javascript using ExternalInterface?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3

I'm looking to call a flash method from a method in javascript and recieve a result:

Example:

**Flash -**

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("getProgress", getProgress) // Javascript to flash

public function getProgress():void {
   ExternalInterface.call("getProgress", progress); // Send progress back to javascript from flash

}
```

**Javascript -**

```
Object.prototype = {
...

getProgress : function() {
   $("#movie").getProgress();
   return progress;
}

...
}
```

Anyone have any idea how to hook all this up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to pass the value of `progress` from flash to javascript or javascript to flash? From the wording of the question it seems that you want to call a flash method from javascript and receive a return value. But then why are you calling `ExternalInterface.call` from flash's `getProgress` method and returning `progress` from the javascript method?

change the flash part to:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("getProgress", getProgress)
public function getProgress():void 
{
    return progress;
}
```

And call

```
alert(window["moviename"].getProgress());    //IE

alert(document["moviename"].getProgress());  //Firefox
```

Checkout [`ExternalInterface` example](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary) in livedocs.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I managed to solve this problem exactly as you suggested. I didn't realize the flash function called from addCallback could return a value!